# Pentadactyl with DuckDuckGo as default search engine

Tags: firefox, pentadactyl

I'd like to set DuckDuckGo as Pentadactyl's default search engine. I added DuckDuckGo's query URL to about:config's keyword.URL variable. I also installed DuckDuckGo's engine via "Add to Firefox" link.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 24):

First, you need to install the search engine at:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/duckduckgo-ssl/

Then you can set the default search engine using:

```
set defsearch=duckduckgo
```

From the help file:

> 'ds''defsearch' string(default: google)
>
> Sets the default search engine. The default search engine is used by
>   :open and related commands for arguments which include no search or
>   bookmark keywords and can't otherwise be converted into URLs or
>   existing file names.
>
> This means that with 'defsearch' set to youtube, :open Tim Minchin
>   behaves exactly as :open youtube Tim Minchin, so long as you don't
>   have a search or bookmark keyword called ‘Tim’.

Comment: You certainly need to add the search engine first. You can do this by opening the search engines dialog with :dialog searchengines

Comment: And how do you add search engines using that dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a bookmark, name it, and set as a default search engine (so no need to install search engine). For example for google.ru add these to `~/.pentadactylrc`:

```
:bmark https://www.google.ru/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&complete=0&site=webhp&source=hp&q=%s -keyword google_ru
set defsearch=google_ru
```